# Invoke-RestMethod : Content-Length or Chunked Encoding cannot be set for an operation that does not write data

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am looking for cURL equivalent command in powershell and then found the below mentioned URL :

https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl

Based on the above URL I tried the below mentioned powershell script in a system which has Powershell version 4.0

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri www.discoposse.com/index.php/feed -Method Get -OutFile C:\Temp\DiscoPosseFeed.xml
```

Once I run the above command I see a xml file in the specified location but if now I specify the encoding as mentioned below:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri www.discoposse.com/index.php/feed -TransferEncoding compress  -Method Get -OutFile C:\Temp\DiscoPosseFeed.xml
```

I am getting an error :

[image]

Can anyone help me to know is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is tha your command line does not write anything on the line. TransferEncoding specifies a value for the **transfer-encoding HTTP response** header. Valid values are Chunked, Compress, Deflate, GZip and Identity.

Comment: I am trying to use the outfile option to generate xml file. I am trying to compress it. Can you please help me by providing any code example Invoke-RestMethod using the TransferEncoding option.

Comment: This param is used for the online response only as documented.